# Showing error when joining video and audio using moviepy library in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, moviepy

I want to join video and audio  with using python but when  i am running the code it is showing error in  my code.Please tell me.
My code:

```
import moviepy.editor as mpe

clip=mpe.VideoFileClip(r'C:\Users\Lucky\Videos\PycharmProjects\firstproj\video.mp4')
audioo=mpe.AudioFileClip(r'C:\Users\Lucky\Videos\PycharmProjects\firstproj\only_audio.mp3')

final_audio=mpe.CompositeAudioClip([audioo,clip.audio])
finalclip=clip.set_audio(final_audio)
finalclip.write_videofile('output.mp4')
```

and  when running the code I  am getting THIS error :
[image]

I am not able to join my video and audio
my video has no audio in the background and i want to join a external audio to my video that will work as my background audio:
or you can tell me that how I can DO this using  python.

Comment: Are you updated to v1.0.3. If so, try on v2.0.0.dev2.

Comment: `clip` does not have audio so `clip.audio` is `None`, and you can't pass `None` into `CompositeAudioClip`.